# Unit Tests Missing on Remote Build Agent

Tags: nunit, build-agent, teamcity-8.0

I recently setup a full build with the default build agent in TeamCity. I set it up so that when I do my coverage analysis, NUnit will dump the results to an xml file. Then I have an additional Build Feature to import that xml report. The defualt agent handles this just fine and will show me the test results after each build.

I created a template from that build and setup another build for a remote machine. To my surprise, it doesn't import the results for that build. TeamCity shows the build as successful and I can view the coverage report, so I know the tests are running. Is there something special I have to do, to get remote build agents to show test reports?

Comment: Is there anything in the TeamCity logs? Check both the server and the build agent, I don't know if test results are transferred via push or pull.

Comment: You know, I'm not sure why I didn't hunt through the logs first... I found this, which is likely the problem: `[09:13:32][NUnit report watcher] No reports found for paths:
[09:13:32][NUnit report watcher] TestResult.xml`